# Dynamodb sorting not working while query on index using QuerySpec

Tags: java, dynamodb-queries

I am new to Dynamodb,  I have a table like below

```
Primary partition key    id (String)
Primary sort key    partition_id (Number)
GSI             status (String)
```

I am trying to fetch record based on id and status but in sorted order by partition_id

```
Iterator<Item> iter = index.query(new QuerySpec()
                .withKeyConditionExpression("#f = :status")
                .withFilterExpression(#id = :id)
                .withNameMap(new NameMap().with("#f", status ).with("#id", ID))
                .withValueMap(new ValueMap()
                        .withString(":status", "SENT")
                        .withString(":id", "1d081455-d333-4bb8-b541-6e8fec58013d"))
                ).iterator();
```

Query works fine but I am not getting the result in sorted order. could you please tell me what is missing?

I have tried  options like                  .withScanIndexForward(true)
.withMaxResultSize(1)

but no effect.

Answer (score 0):

Just like your primary hash_key and sort_key, you need to define a hash_key and sort_key for GSI and then query using GSI's hash_key and sort based on GSI's sort_key

refer: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/how-to-use-dynamodb-global-secondary-indexes-to-improve-query-performance-and-reduce-costs/